# Vue JS conditional rendering on first time opening the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue component which should render on the first time opening the page but I am a bit confused with the logic of this. I am using localStorage to verify the wasVisited item, I should set it to 1 somewhere so the next time the view that triggers the modal is opened the modal doesn't show, I'm just not sure where, mounted() doesn't seem to be the place I need to set it.

```
<template v-if="localStorage.getItem('wasVisited') === null">
<div>
    <b-modal ref="disc" title="Hello" ok-only ok-variant="light" size="lg" body-bg-variant="dark" header-bg-variant="dark" header-text-variant="light" body-text-variant="light" footer-bg-variant="dark" footer-text-variant="light" title-class="text-light">
        <div class="text-justify modal-text">
            <p>Hi from modal</p>
        </div>
    </b-modal>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        showModal() {
            this.$refs['disc'].show()
        },
        hideModal() {
            this.$refs['disc'].hide()
        },
    },

    mounted() {
        console.log('Modal mounted.');
        this.showModal();
        localStorage.setItem('wasVisited', '1');
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to write your code should be

```
<template>
<div>
    <b-modal ref="disc" title="Hello" ok-only ok-variant="light" size="lg" body-bg-variant="dark" header-bg-variant="dark" header-text-variant="light" body-text-variant="light" footer-bg-variant="dark" footer-text-variant="light" title-class="text-light">
        <div class="text-justify modal-text">
            <p>Hi from modal</p>
        </div>
    </b-modal>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        showModal() {
            this.$refs['disc'].show()
        },
        hideModal() {
            this.$refs['disc'].hide()
        },
    },

    mounted() {
        console.log('Modal mounted.');
        if(localStorage.getItem('wasVisited') === null) this.showModal();
        localStorage.setItem('wasVisited', '1');
    }
}
</script>
```

Basically what I did was, I removed your **v-if** from your template and instead added it to your **mounted** property, this way if the localStorage hasn't been set, automatically the function to show modal is called. And at the same time we assign a value to **wasVisited**

Comment: how could I test if this work on localhost? It's not showing it anytime now, not even when i initialize the server

Comment: nvm, i opened it on incognito and it showed the modal, confirmed it works, thank you

Comment: Don't forget to clear your localStorage if you want to confirm it works without being Incognito